# How to access nth level of a nested array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I would like to write a function that goes through a nested array and returns a sum of n values (see example bellow).

```
var children = {
  value: 1,
  children: {
    value: 3,
    children: {
      value: 2,
      children: {
        value: 5,
        children: {
          value: 3
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think that I need to use recursion and this is how I imagine it should go:

1) Function takes params 'array' and a 'targetLevel' (a depth to which it should go) and returns sum of 'values' from level[0] to level[nth].

2) At the beginning, function checks if level inside is equal to param level (if so, it adds current level to var value and then returns it).

3) Until condition is met following happens in each iteration:

- result += value
- auxiliary var level++ (default set to 0) so I can track on which level I currently am
- store given array without current level in var children
- call the function with updated params until depth condition is met

Example:

countNthValue(children, 3) would return number 6 -> value on level[0] + value on level[1] + value on level[2]

---

So, am I even grasping the basic concept correctly (recursively call the function, each iteration store smaller part of array)? If so, how do I write the function correctly?

If not and this is just a gibberish, how do I access nth level of a nested array?

Comment: you show nested objects.

Answer (score 0):

Base on the object you gave the answer is 14

```js
var children = {
  value: 1,
  children: {
    value: 3,
    children: {
      value: 2,
      children: {
        value: 5,
        children: {
          value: 3
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

 function sumChildren(children){
      if(children == undefined|| children== null) return 0;
      return children.value + sumChildren(children.children);
    
    }

console.log(sumChildren(children));
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

```
function getSum(obj, depth){
  var num = 0;
  if(depth - 1)
       num = getSum(obj.child, depth -1);
   return num + obj.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var children = {
  value: 1,
  children: {
    value: 3,
    children: {
      value: 2,
      children: {
        value: 5,
        children: {
          value: 3
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


function countNthValue (array, depth, current){

    if(typeof current === 'undefined') {
        current = 1;
    }

    if (depth > current && array.children) {
        return array.value + countNthValue(array.children, depth, current+1);
    } else {
        return array.value;
    }
}

// Test
console.log(countNthValue (children, 1));
console.log(countNthValue (children, 2));
console.log(countNthValue (children, 3));
console.log(countNthValue (children, 4));
console.log(countNthValue (children, 5));
console.log(countNthValue (children, 6));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do like this

```js
var children = {
                value: 1,
                children: {
                           value: 3,
                           children: {
                                      value: 2,
                                      children: {
                                                 value: 5,
                                                 children: {
                                                            value: 3
                                                           }
                                                }
                                     }
                          }
               },
        sums = (e, v) => !!e.children ? sums(e.children, v + e.value) : v + e.value;
document.write("<pre>" + sums(children,0) + "</pre>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a combination of arrays and objects with a function for the recursive call an inside [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for summing the values.

```js
var children = [{
        value: 1,
        children: [{
            value: 3,
            children: [{
                value: 2,
                children: [{
                    value: 5,
                    children: [{
                        value: 3
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }],
    i;

function getLevel(array, level) {
    return ~level && Array.isArray(array) ?
        array.reduce(function (r, a) {
            return r + a.value + getLevel(a.children, level - 1);
        }, 0) :
        0;
}

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    document.write(getLevel(children, i) + '<br>');
}
```